# Get history of Youtube app

Tags: android, youtube

Do Youtube app save the history of searched or watched videos somewhere local, on the mobile phone? If this happens, there is a any way to get this history using a android app?

Comment: It does save your search history locally, but it's probably not available.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not YouTube saves the search history locally is something you'd have to ask the YouTube developers.

However, if it does, the data is most certainly not available to other applications.